# CosmosDB Airflow

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, airflow

Could someone try to help me, creating the connection between airflow and cosmos db?
While I try to use AzureCosmosInsertDocumentOperator, I get this error:

```
azure.cosmos.errors.HTTPFailure: Status code: 405
{"code":"MethodNotAllowed","message":"RequestHandler.Post"}
```

Regarding the connection on airflow:
[image: Airflow Connection]

Comment: Have you tried to connect to CosmoDB outside Airflow using those credentials? From your error it looks like the credentials are ok but POST request fails suggesting possible bug in the operator.

Comment: yes, they work outside airflow, but not on airflow